# Sequence and series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence defined by $$a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3 - a_n}, \text{ if } n \geq 1$$

Does $\{a_n\}$ converge or diverge?

My solution:

I just wrote down some terms.

$a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1, a_3 = \frac{1}{2}, a_4 = 5/13, a_5 = 13/34$. Basically eventually $a_n$ will be zero, so I say this converges to $\frac{1}{3}$. What is the most simple but a good solution to prove this?

Comment: Hint: The definition of a convergent sequence.

Comment: $\exists \frac{1}{3} \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N$, then $|a_n - \frac{1}{3}| < $ ___

Comment: Thats the WTS. But how do I show that? (I'm not use to doing this without being given what exactly $a_n$) is, can I say |$\frac{1}{3-a_n} - 1/3|$ ?

Comment: This sequence does not converge to $\frac13$: if, for some $n$, $a_n$ were very close to $\frac13$, $a_{n+1}$ would be very close to $\frac{1}{3 - \frac13} = \frac38$, which is further away from $\frac13$ again.

Comment: Are you saying this question does not converge?

Comment: Thank you. Whoever duplicated this